# How to force Google OAuth popup in Firebase when user already authenticated previously?

Tags: oauth, firebase, google-oauth, firebase-authentication

Whenever a user has previously authenticated with Google, it automatically defaults to logging them in with THAT account on subsequent attempts.  I want to eliminate this and force the popup/redirect so that a user with multiple google accounts can choose which one to use.  How?

Background:

The automatic logging in feature is proving problematic for me as I have a whitelisted set of e-mails for users allowed to use my app.  If a Google user chooses the wrong account when first logging in, they can't go back and choose the one associated to their whitelisted e-mail.

Answer (score 3):

Just as @nvnagr said, you can do this with the following code:

```
var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
provider.setCustomParameters({
   'prompt': 'select_account'
});
```

But I think you need to update the firebase version to 3.6.0 something.

Answer (score 1):

Google supports a parameter in authentication url to deal with this issue.

If you add prompt=select_account in your request to Google authentication, it'll force the user to do an account selection. See the details and other values of prompt.

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#authenticationuriparameters

I'm not sure if there is an easy way to add this parameter through firebase api.

Answer (score 0):

When you're calling the oAuth function, you can pass a third options parameter to make the authentication last for the session only. This should solve your problem. [Docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/google.html#section-logging-in)

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com");
ref.authWithOAuthPopup("google", function(error, authData) {
  if (error) {
    console.log("Login Failed!", error);
  } else {
    console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);
  }
}, {
  remember: 'sessionOnly'
});
```